# What is the correct coordinate parameter format/syntax to find the intersection of two rectangles

Tags: ruby, parameters

I have this exercise:

```
Write a function, `rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)` and returns the
intersection of the two.

Rectangles are represented as a pair of coordinate-pairs: the
bottom-left and top-right coordinates (given in `[x, y]` notation).
```

I am trying to figure out how to call the method with `puts` and test out some value so I make sure I understand this problem. I've been struggling with this one for some reason.

This is the answer to the problem:

```
def rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)
  x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][0]].max
  x_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][0]].min

  y_min = [rect1[0][1], rect2[0][1]].max
  y_max = [rect1[1][1], rect2[1][1]].min

  return nil if ((x_max < x_min) || (y_max < y_min))
  return [[x_min, y_min], [x_max, y_max]]
end
```

When I try to call the method using `puts` with code like this:

```
v = ([0,0][2,1])
w = ([1,0][3,1])
puts rec_intersection(v, w)
```

I get the following error:

```
calc.rb:2:in `rec_intersection': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMetho
dError)
        from calc.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

And when I try this:

```
v = [(0,0)(2,1)]
w = [(1,0)(3,1)]
puts rec_intersection(v, w)
```

I get this error:

```
calc.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
v = [(0,0)(2,1)]
```

What is the right format to pass the rectangle coordinate parameters to be able to call the functions with `puts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This two lines are wrong:

```
v = ([0,0][2,1])
w = ([1,0][3,1])
```

Your code defines an array `[0,0]` and than calls the `[]` method on that array ([see](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)) with the arguments 2 and 1. That means: start at the second position and take 1 element from the array. What leads to an empty array...

You need to define an array of arrays like this:

```
v = [ [0,0], [2,1] ]
w = [ [1,0], [3,1] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Now that your question has been answered, I would like to suggest a way of doing this that I think is more Ruby-like, as it does not make use of indices.  It also generalizes to dimensions higher than two (though that may be of no immediate interest).

Note that regardless of which method you use, you can generalize it to determining the intersection of any number of rectangles by first determining the intersection of the first two, then the intersection of that result with the third rectangle, and so on.

**Code**

```
def rec_intersection(rec1,rec2)
  rec1.zip(rec2, [:max, :min])
      .map { |*a,method| a.transpose.map { |b| b.send method } }
end
```

**Examples**

Suppose your overlapping rectangles looked like this.

[image: Overlapping rectangles]

The two rectangles are:

```
rec1 = [[0,0],[3,4]]
rec2 = [[2,2],[5,5]]
```

Therefore:

```
rec_intersection(rec1,rec2)
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 4]]
```

One nice thing about this method is that it can be applied to overlapping boxes (*orthotopes* or *hyperrectangles*) in any number of dimensions.  Suppose you have these two boxes in three dimensions:

[image]

The two rectangles are:

```
rec1 = [[0,0,0],[3,4,3]]
rec2 = [[2,3,1],[5,8,5]]
```

Therefore:

```
rec_intersection(rec1,rec2)
  #=> [[2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 3]]
```

**Explanation**

Consider the first example above:

```
rec1 = [[0,0],[3,4]]
rec2 = [[2,2],[5,5]]
```

We use [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) in order to compare the lower-left and upper-right coordinates of the two rectangles:

```
c = rec1.zip(rec2, [:max, :min])
  #=> [[[0, 0], [2, 2], :max], [[3, 4], [5, 5], :min]]
```

Notice that we also pass methods to each of these arrays: [Enumerable#max](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) for the first, [Enumerable#min](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) for the second.

[Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) passes each element of `c` (of which there are two) into its block and assigns values to the block variables `a` and `method`.  The first is:

```
a => [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
method => :max
```

Next we apply [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) to `a`:

```
d = a.transpose
  #=> [[0, 2], [0, 2]]
```

and then map each of these arrays into the maximum of the elements by sending `max`to the array:

```
d.map { |b| b.send method } #=> [2,2]
```

This gives us the maxima of the x and y coordinates, resulting in the first element of `b` being replaced with `[2,2]`.  Next, `map` passes:

```
[[3, 4], [5, 5], #<Proc:0x00000101138498>]
```

into the block, assigning it to the block variables:

```
a  => [[3, 4], [5, 5]]
method => :min
```

Since `:min` computes the minimum of an array, we obtain:

```
d = a.transpose
  #=> [[3, 5], [4, 5]]
d.map { |b| b.send method } #=> [3,4]
```

The second element of `b` is therefore replaced with `[3,4]` and the method returns:

```
[[2, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Hmm, could you find a way to use `Enumerable#minmax` to remove the `done_lower_left` toggle?

Comment: Hmmm.  Don't know, @Mark.  Trouble is, `minmax` and `minmax_by` apply to one array, whereas I want `min` to appy to one array and `max` to another, but I'll think about it. I also considered multiplying some values by -1 before and after, but didn't like that.  It would be nice to get rid of the toggle.

Comment: Woww.. Answer with a diagram..Excellent +1.. Cary, Great!

Comment: Mark, I made a change to the method that gets rid of the toggle. Thanks again for the push.